# How do I make a copy of WordPress to other folder

Tags: multisite, migration, directory

Currently I have my WordPress up and running fine on the root folder of my production server. Now I would like to copy almost everything (except database and url) into other folder for testing purpose, lets say `/newsite`.

1. What's the most convenient way to do this ?
2. Do I have to play with the `.htaccess` file ? At this moment I don't even use this file on the production server, Is this bad ?
3. Will Wordpress multisite be able to separate production and development site ? How about the database separation ?

Basically in the end I would want to have

- www.mydomain.com as the main site
- www.mydomain.com/newsite as the testing site

I have full access with FTP. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory This may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move wordpress you should this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

I guess you want to create a development environment, and because you never edit core files of Wordpress you don't have to copy Wordpress itself because the only thing you are changing is the theme folder. And you don't want to install Wordpress a second time in a sub-directory so maybe you should try **creating a sub-domain**: http://semperfiwebdesign.com/blog/setting-up-a-wordpress-development-environment-on-your-hosted-server/

Comment: I will need to change the content and theme of the development website without affecting the production site. Is this the one I am looking for ?

Comment: Yeah, download the theme folder you are using. Then install the same version of Wordpress on the sub-domain. When you finish your development version you can install only the theme on the production environment so you can switch the theme on and off so you will always have a fall-back.

Comment: That is how I use it anyway. And for full safety I also use a version control system. That would be the next step. Open this page, and search for the head "The Environments": http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/general/professional-wordpress-development-environments/